# Why square root for RSE?

Tags: regression, residuals, standard-error

$$\text{RSE}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-2}\text{RSS}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-2}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\hat{y_i})^2}$$

Why should we put square root to get RSE ? what for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $y$ is in units of meters. Then the squared errors $\sum (y_i - \hat y_i)^2$ are in units of meters squared, whereas RSE is in units of meters again. This puts it on a comparable scale to the data points, making the resulting numbers much more interpretable.

Geometrically, you can think of the square root as corresponding to taking the *length* of the error vector (the distance between the true vector of all the labels and the estimated vector of all labels), so the square-then-root structure shouldn't be too surprising.

Comment: +1. The OP may find a reminder of Pythagoras' theorem to be helpful.